# gnuplot 5 on CentOs with png support

Tags: centos, software-installation, compiling, gnuplot

Help me please to make gnuplot 5 working on CentOs with png terminal

1. I did not find rpm package for gnuplot 5 on Centos- may be you can point me?
2. I downloaded sources compiled and installed - no png support
3. I installed libgd-devel, configured and installed gnuplot again - no png support
4. I inspected config.log, found missing library - installed libpng12-devel
5. Configure and make gnuplot again - this time error

   In file included from term.h:293:0,
                from term.c:1202:
    ../term/gd.trm: In function ‘GIF_text’:
    ../term/gd.trm:2741:6: error: ‘gdDisposalRestorePrevious’ undeclared (first use in this function)
   ? gdDisposalRestorePrevious
     ^
    ../term/gd.trm:2741:6: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
    ../term/gd.trm:2742:6: error: ‘gdDisposalNone’ undeclared (first use in this function)
   : gdDisposalNone,
     ^

What I'm doing wrong? How can I make gnuplot 5 compiles?

Comment: Paste here how you invoke configure script, and how you've installed libgd and libpng12

Comment: sudo yum install libpng12-devel
      sudo yum install gd-devel
     ./configure --prefix=/usr

Comment: What version of Centos is this? On Centos 7 gnuplot 5.2.0 configures and makes without error following `yum -y install libpng-devel gd-devel`

Comment: If I remove 'libpng12-devel" and install only libpng-devel gd-devel as you wrote, it compiles, but without png jpeg support

It is CentOs 7